# Apache James SMTPS not responding

Tags: apache, email, ssl, smtp, james

I am having an Issue using Apache James SMTPS (I am using it for a project using secure mail). I have setup the server according to the official docs. Receiving of mails seem to work fine via SSL. Sending of mails do not work. I have attempted to connect using openssl with the following result

```
root@ubuntuServer:/usr/local# openssl s_client -connect localhost:465
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
   i:/C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
issuer=/C=za/ST=gauteng/L=pretoria/O=private/OU=private/CN=192.168.1.21
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1600 bytes and written 279 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: 5371009C91492E135875BA0590DFFA8387EDF0451A05020BD429B5A6B39A2524
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 279820DCA6C216E2C559F61705D64059F8F888C131EF16C71628B238C5B8A46F3A1DCEF7F73843B3C937F8ABBC241D04
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1399914653
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
220 ubuntuServer SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.2) ready Mon, 12 May 2014 19:10:52 +0200 (SAST)
EHLO localhost
```

After I entered the  I get no response from the server. Thunderbird does something similar. It connects but the just times out.

I can't seem to find anything wrong in the logs (smtp log just says that someone connected)
The closes thing I can find to an error is in the mailet log

```
12/05/14 18:57:34 INFO  James.Mailet: RemoteAddrNotInNetwork: Authorized addresses: [127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255]
12/05/14 18:57:34 INFO  James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: maxRetries is larger than total number of attempts     specified. Increasing last delayTime with 19 attempts
12/05/14 18:57:34 INFO  James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Delay of 21600000 msecs is now attempted: 20 times
```

But I am connecting from localhost so this should work anyways as I understand it.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I should also mention that if I disable the SSL I have no problems sending mails via telnet.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Add the `-CAfile` option to the `openssl s_client` command, and specify the self-signed certificate. `tls1` and `-servername` would be additional options to ensure SNI is used. See the [s_client(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) docs.

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding -crlf to the end of the openssl call. I now have new issues with setting the recipient but will post a new question if I cannot get it solved

Comment: The only problem I see in the output you posted is `verify error:num=18:self signed certificate`.

Comment: @jww Yes that solved it. I had to add the certificate to the trusted list. Thanks